# How do I stop Adobe Reader from showing that sidebar on the right?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I regularly use Adobe Reader to view PDF's, but I have to close the side bar on the right all the time.

Does anyone know how I can permanently hide it?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ehlUvJH.png]